# Panel apps try to launch in xterm, even though it isn't installed

Tags: launcher, panel, applet, mate, virtual-terminal

I have some panel applications that launch terminals, but when I click on them, they say xterm failed. Well yeah, `xterm` isn't installed, nor do I want it.

I want mate-terminal to come up instead. How do I configure that to happen?

This is Ubuntu server 12.04 with a mate desktop. I have MATE Terminal 1.6.1 installed.

Here is the error:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

I tried :

```
export TERM=mate-terminal
```

But the change was not lasting, nor did it effect the panel launcher.

---

UPDATE2:

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator  
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator: /usr/bin/mate-terminal
Nothing to configure.
```

Not sure what list it is, but this doesn't seem to work. 
Ok, so Ill try this command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator mate-terminal /usr/bin/mate-terminal 50
update-alternatives: priority must be an integer

Usage: update-alternatives [<option> ...] <command>

Commands:
  --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
    [--slave <link> <name> <path>] ...
                           add a group of alternatives to the system.
  --remove <name> <path>   remove <path> from the <name> group alternative.
  --remove-all <name>      remove <name> group from the alternatives system.
  --auto <name>            switch the master link <name> to automatic mode.
  --display <name>         display information about the <name> group.
  --query <name>           machine parseable version of --display <name>.
  --list <name>            display all targets of the <name> group.
  --get-selections         list master alternative names and their status.
  --set-selections         read alternative status from standard input.
  --config <name>          show alternatives for the <name> group and ask the
                           user to select which one to use.
  --set <name> <path>      set <path> as alternative for <name>.
  --all                    call --config on all alternatives.

<link> is the symlink pointing to /etc/alternatives/<name>.
  (e.g. /usr/bin/pager)
<name> is the master name for this link group.
  (e.g. pager)
<path> is the location of one of the alternative target files.
  (e.g. /usr/bin/less)
<priority> is an integer; options with higher numbers have higher priority in
  automatic mode.

Options:
  --altdir <directory>     change the alternatives directory.
  --admindir <directory>   change the administrative directory.
  --log <file>             change the log file.
  --force                  allow replacing files with alternative links.
  --skip-auto              skip prompt for alternatives correctly configured
                           in automatic mode (relevant for --config only)
  --verbose                verbose operation, more output.
  --quiet                  quiet operation, minimal output.
  --help                   show this help message.
  --version                show the version.
~$ sudo update-alternatives --set /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator mate-terminal /usr/bin/mate-terminal 50
```

So then, "--install" doesnt seem to be an option. ok, maybe "--set" is what was meant... but that doesnt work right.

I also looked in system>preferences>preferred applications
where mate terminal is listed as the default terminal.

here is uname -a to confirm my Ubuntu usage:

```
Linux X 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:42:40 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: it depends on the panel applications you use... maybe you can set it in the preferences....

but i think they usually try to start the default terminal - have you tried to update this? sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

Comment: it says $ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator: /usr/bin/mate-terminal
Nothing to configure.

Comment: are you running Mint or ubuntu + Mate.  According to this - this is a very specific Mint issue: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/issues/57

Comment: I am running ubuntu, though i just observed the same problem on a friends computer, where he is running Mint.

Comment: How are your panel applications launched? In particular, what does the `Exec` line of the corresponding .desktop file contain?

Comment: @j0h, Seth's answer seems the correct one. But I would like to ask you if you can test my answer first, see if it works. Run `sudo rm /usr/bin/xterm` to remove it. Then use Seth's solution. I just want to see, if my thinking was in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was tooling around in synaptic, which I installed later to help me figure this out.

I noticed GNOME-terminal wasn't installed, so I installed it.
Suddenly my links work properly now.

To be certain, I uninstalled it, and deleted the link I made recommended by Sneetsher

Once uninstalled I was getting the same errors.
When I install GNOME-terminal again, it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: You are right, mate-terminal does not have a wrapper. I have checked a fresh install it uses `gnome-terminal.wrapper` provided by `gnome-terminal` package. Also `x-terminal-emulator` is pointing to that wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Find `mate-terminal` in the list and enter the number beside it.

If mate-terminal is not in the list you can add it with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator mate-terminal /path/to/executable 50
```

Where `/path/to/executable` is the path where mate-terminal resides.

The `$TERM` variable doesn't tell you what terminal emulator you're using, it just tells you what *type* of emulator you are using. Most emulators are `xterm` type.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator mate-terminal /usr/bin/mate-terminal 50

This doesnt seem to have worked, or rather it seems to have caused other problems? (commands like clear, arent working now??). My shell is behaving oddly now though. How might I undo this change?

Comment: @j0h That is strange. Did my first command not work for you? Please confirm that you are indeed on Ubuntu and not Mint. I'll test this out myself (I'll have to use a different terminal though). Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12.04 server kernel with mate installed.
@Seth

Comment: @j0h Was something wrong with my first command? Did you replace `/path/to/executable` with the appropriate file?

Comment: yes, i replaced that with the output of "$which mate-terminal" /usr/bin/mate-terminal. Hay, what is the "50"?

Comment: @j0h You aren't answering my first question. The 50 is the priority, though I was told this didn't matter, you might try changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Old **Non Working** answer, Make a link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mate-terminal /usr/bin/xterm
```

---

It didn't work because `mate-terminal` is not a drop-in replacement for `xterm` it needs an xterm wrapper. I think is the same problem with `x-terminal-emulator` solution, which should point to xterm replacement terminal (or an xterm wrapper).

What it seems happening here, if `x-terminal-emulator` is not set, windows manager look for `xterm` which is the standard terminal for Xorg (in this case, not installed).

A bug report report was already filled against Mint 14 for missing wrapper, [lp-bug#1238964](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1238964) . Also upstream bug report Mint 13 [github-issue#9](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/issues/9), stated as fixed.

I could confirm that Mint 16 contains `mate-terminal.wrapper`.

For earlier releases:

- `mate-terminal.wrapper` could be downloaded from source repository of [mate-terminal](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal), set it up using `update-alternatives` as mentioned in Seth's solution
- Or just install other alternative desktops terminal which have a wrapper like `gnome-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal`,.. as j0h's answer. Any of them will configure the `x-terminal-emulator` to its own wrapper.

Comment: `/usr/bin/xterm` doesn't exist, so will this still work?

Comment: @Seth ,`Failed to execute child process`, If the application calls `xterm` as sub process, this will work. What confirm this is `No such file or directory`, the application does call `xterm` command as sub/child process. This what I'm thinking of.

Comment: That is interesting. I was more referring to creating a link to a non existent location, but maybe I don't understand how links work.

Comment: @Sneetsher That "works" but the launcher closes immediately after opening the terminal... The commands are things like ssh

Comment: @j0h, ah sorry may be I miss some thing here. I  may be I should point to the wrapper not terminal itself. Could you run `sudo updatedb` then add to the question output of `locate terminal | grep bin/`. I'm looking to see if you have `mate-terminal.wrapper`

Comment: Well, the bounty needs to go someplace, and I see you made a post on launchpad for a fix to the bug, so Ill award bounty for that.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1238964

Comment: @j0h, I will update my answer. To be more relevant to the question problem and the mentioned bug. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me in Mate 15.05:

```
sudo apt-get install GNOME-terminal
```